# Saving opening tabiyas in scid

Tags: opening, scid

When I use scid to study an opening I do the following:

- start new game
- play through the opening up to a position I am interested in
- search database for "current board"

I am sure there must be a more efficient way to do this. Is it possible to save positions and use these saved positions in searches?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I don't understand your question correctly, but if you don't want to enter moves manually every time to reach a certain position you can simply create a database for all the openings\tabiyas you're interested in and add it to your bookmarks. So, whenever you need some position you open that database via the bookmark you created (it's much faster than going through open dialog box and looking for the file on your hard drive) and copy that position from there.

Btw, you can also download eco.pgn file containing all the known openings here: https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/

Then, if you want to see the names of openings and variations that the file contains in your Game List you need to do the following: open eco.pgn as a text file in a plain text editor of your choice and replace "Opening" with "White" and "Variation" with "Black". While doing so, don't forget to enable "match case" option. That's it.